# Registrar dos tablas al mismo tiempo usando como FK en una tabla el ID de la otra, en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, lógica

Tengo dos tablas

`Usuario` y `Docente`

Lo que quiero hacer es registrar un usuario, e inmediatamente después registrar un nuevo Docente, pero este docente, deberá tener como **FK** la **PK** del **usuario** que acabo de crear.

En la lógica a nivel **SQL** lo que tengo en mente, seria algo así:

```
`Insert usuario......{{Aqui haria el insert de mi usuario}}`
```

Inmediatamente debajo haria otra consulta usando la funcion

```
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`
```

Para obtener el ultimo ID registrado en mi tabla Usuarios y con este ID registrar mi Docente

```
`Insert Docente......{{Aqui haria el insert de mi Docente colocando como FK el ID de usuario}}`
```

Pregunto esto, porque habrán muchos usuarios y docentes registrándose al mismo tiempo y tengo miedo de que en los pocos microsegundos entre registrar a mi usuario, extraer su `ID` y registrar el **docente**, otro usuario se registre y hayan errores.

Es una duda que tengo y quisiera poder aclararla o si esta es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

**PDTA:** Estoy trabajando con *LARAVEL*, así que me gustaría saber como puedo hacer esto mediante este **framework**

Comment: Creo que formule mal la pregunta y aqui esta mejor explicada. Pensaba en eliminarla y hacer una nueva, pero no me permitio eliminarla.
De todas formas, creo que aqui mi pregunta tiene un mejor planteamiento

Comment: ¿Esto es de **Laravel**? @AldahirRuizValdez ¿o solo **SQL**?

Comment: Esto es en laravel. @josbert

Comment: ¿Usas **Eloquent** o solo **constructores de consulta**? o sea `DB::table(...`

Comment: Bien bien, no nos frenemos por eso, te daré una respuesta amplia para ambos casos, también modificare la pregunta para mejorar un poco el contexto ya que es una duda muy común y sumamente *googleada*

Comment: Con respecto a lo que menciona @BetaM tiene razón deberías procurar en lo posible modificar una pregunta antigua y darle seguimiento a esa, antes de abrir una nueva preguntando lo mismo. Aunque técnicamente no esta mal, allá queda reflejada a modo de solo **SQL** y acá con **Laravel**

Answer (score 1):

Bien para esto, **Laravel** facilita muchos las cosas, ya sea si estas usando **Eloquent** junto con esos **modelos** relacionados, o solo usas los **Query Builder**

Empezando por [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent). Suponiendo que el la **tabla** `usuarios` tiene un modelo llamado **Usuario** y a su vez ese modelo tiene una relación con el modelo **Docente** puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

**Supongamos que esta es la relación:**

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    /**
     * Relación uno a uno con el modelo Docente
     */
    public function docente()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Docente::class, 'usuario_id');
    }
}
```

Seria tan sencillo como usar el método [save()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) que proporcionan las relaciones de **Eloquent**; como dice en su documentación:

> **Eloquent** proporciona métodos convenientes para agregar nuevos modelos a las relaciones. Por ejemplo, quizá necesites insertar un
> nuevo **Comment** para un modelo **Post**. En lugar de establecer
> manualmente el atributo `post_id` en el **Comment**, puedes insertar
> el **Comment** directamente con el método `save` de la relación

**Un ejemplo, ajustado a que lo nosotros tenemos aquí:**

```php
/** 
 * Insertamos un nuevo usuario y a su vez, el método "create()" nos devolverá el mismo,
 * incluyendo su PK autoincremental id 
 */ 
$usuario = App\Usuario::create(
    [
        'nombre' => 'Juan',
        'email' => 'juan@ejemplo.com'
    ]
);

// Creamos al Docente
$docente = new App\Docente([
    'nombre' => 'José',
    'email' => 'josé@otro.ejemplo.com'
]);

// Insertamos al docente en la relación
$usuario->docente()->save($docente);
```

Esto automáticamente creara la **relación** es decir, le asignara a la **FK** `usuario_id` el `id` del **usuario** recién creado.

Daría lo mismo para las relaciones de **uno a muchos**, y para relaciones de **muchos a muchos** puedes usar el metodo [attach()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

**Ojo**, para poder insertar campos con el método [create()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates), es necesario que estos campos estén dentro de la propiedad `$fillable` del modelo, o sea que estén en la lista blanca para asignación masiva.

---

**Usando Query Builder (*constructor de consultas*)**

Por otro lado, usando **Query Builder** la cosa obviamente cambia. Puede ser mas sencillo incluso, dependiendo de como lo veas, ya que no requiere configuración en **modelos** obviamente.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

// Insertamos al usuario, obteniendo su PK autoincremental
$id = DB::table('usuarios')
      ->insertGetId([
          'nombre' => 'Juan',
          'email' => 'juan@ejemplo.com'
      ]);

// Ahora simplemente insertamos el docente
DB::table('docentes')
->insert([
    'nombre' => 'José',
    'email' => 'josé@otro.ejemplo.com',
    'usuario_id' => $id // le asignamos la FK obtenida antes
]);
```

Usando el método [insertGetId()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#auto-incrementing-ids), obtenemos el `id` de la fila recién insertada, para así usarla como **FK** en la tabla relacionada.

---

Todo lo que necesitas saber esta en la documentación de **Laravel** y la verdad esta muy bien explicado. Espero haberte ayudado ;) un saludo

Answer (score -1):

Después del primer insert prueba con `Select @@IDENTITY` te devolverá el `id` del insert antes realizado

Comment: *@@IDENTITY* ¿existe en MySQL?